# Oracle run select with timeout option

Tags: oracle, prepared-statement, database-administration

Is there any way to run select on oracle database with timeout properties ?

If yes please give me example

Comment: Timeout properties of what ?  JDBC, ODBC, OCI, J2EE, Oracle database settings or [something completely different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Now_for_Something_Completely_Different) ?

Comment: [This is covered pretty well on this OTN thread](https://community.oracle.com/message/1362604). Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option is,

1 - your program should control the execution time, and decide if should abort or continue

2 - or use the RESOURCE_MANAGER

Check the links

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_resmgr.htm#i1003006

Check also this paper in how to implement

https://www.pythian.com/blog/oracle-limiting-query-runtime-without-killing-the-session/